# How to close fancybox and reset input form values

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

Hello I have a contact us form using fancybox, and I want to reset/clear the form input values when fancybox closes (either when user clicks outside the popup or using the "close" popup button)

the element which holds the fancybox content is 'inline' so my guess was:

```
...
$("#fancybox-overlay").fancybox({

'afterClosed': function() {
        $('#inline').hide(250, function() {
            $('#name input').val('');
            $('#phone input').val('');
            $('#email input').val('');
            $('#subject input').val('');
            $('#msgcontent textarea').val('');
            $('#security_code input').val('');

            $('#name input').removeClass('error');
            $('#phone input').removeClass('error');
            $('#email input').removeClass('error');
            $('#subject input').removeClass('error');
            $('#msgcontent textarea').removeClass('error');
            $('#security_code input').removeClass('error');
            $('#security_code_error').html('');
        });
    }
});
```

But the result is as below:
before :
[image]

and after:
[image]

Any help to make the form values reset/cleared during a "close" action from clicking outside the popup, will be very much appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
The html requested by @Spokey is:

```
<div id="inline" style="z-index:999999;">
    <h2 class="popupheader">...Contact Us: Send us a Message</h2>

    <div style="margin:2% 8%;background:#fff;border-radius:5px;width:auto;box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px #bbb;">
        <p style="display:inline-block;padding:10px;">
            ...
        </p>
        <p style="display:inline-block;padding:10px;float:right;">
            ...
        </p>
    </div>
    <form id="contact" name="contact" action="#" method="post">
        <label for="name">Your Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="txt" style="margin-left: 3px">
        <br>
        <label for="phone">Your Phone No.</label>
        <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" class="txt" >
        <br>
        <label for="email">Your E-mail</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="txt">
        <br>
        <label for="subject">Subject</label>
        <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" class="txt" size="45">
        <br>
        <label for="msgcontent">Enter a Message</label>
        <textarea id="msgcontent" name="msgcontent" class="txtarea" style="margin-left: 3px"></textarea>

        <br>

        <label for="security_code" style="width:auto;">Verify you are human</label>
        <img border="0" id="captcha" src="../../image.php" alt="">&nbsp;<a href="JavaScript: new_captcha();">
        <img border="0" alt="" src="../../images/refresh.png" align="bottom"></a>
        <input name="security_code" id="security_code" class="txt" style="width:150px;vertical-align: top;margin: 0px;" size="20" type="text" >
        <span id="security_code_error" name="security_code_error" style="background:#fefefe;color:red;"></span><? /*<div class="field_error error_pos"><?php if($error['security_code'] != "") echo $error['security_code']; ?></div> */ ?>
<br />
<hr style="color:#f2f2f2;border:1px solid #f2f2f2;width:auto;">
        <button id="send" name="send">Send Message</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I suppose your are using Fancybox v2.x. The method's name is 'afterClose' and not 'afterClosed'. Maybe a typing error.

Comment: Thanks @Panos for spotting that!! Saved!!

Answer (score 2):

And you can do it a lot more easier and cleaner. E.g. if you want to clear all input fields just do it that way without repetitive and spaghetti code:

```
document.getElementById("yourFormId").reset();
```

Comment: +1 : @luhfluh just wrap it inside the `afterClose` callback like `afterClose: function () {
            document.getElementById("contact").reset();
        }` ... where `contact` refers to your form with `id="contact"` ... see http://jsfiddle.net/VakZ5/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to hide `#inline`, as the plugin will hide it itself

```
$("#fancybox-overlay").fancybox({
'afterClose': function() {
        $('#inline input, #inline textarea').val('');
        $('#inline').children().removeClass('error');
        $('#security_code_error').empty();
    }
});
```

NOTE changed 'afterClosed' for fancybox2
to 'afterClose' (typo error)

Comment: Thanks Spokey for ur suggestion, but still not working, and still same effect (inputs not reset, and form appears like in "after"). Any work around this?